# method similar to set_index in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

What is the method in pyspark DataFrame object which is similar to pandas.DataFrame.set_index? Can you please suggest?

Comment: Pyspark dataframes don't have indexes. What do you need it for?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have idea that Pyspark dataframes don't have indexes. Thanks for the information