# How to make index when insert dataframe to mongodb via pyspark

Tags: mongodb, pyspark

need some help please.

How can I add an index while inserting dataframe to mongodb like this?

```
my_dataframe.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append").save()
```

My dataframe contains a field named my_custom_id and I want to make this one my new index instead of the default index added by mongodb.

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783273/method-similar-to-set-index-in-pyspark

Comment: It doesn't respond to the question, it's not the same problem.

Comment: The default index in Mongodb is "_id". I would like create an index "my_custom_rowid" from my "custom_rowid" in the dataframe.